# Excel VBA integration with IE, getting an unusual error 462

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use Excel's VBA to automate a task involving a website. Here's the relevant code I have:

```
Sub test()
    Dim IE as Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://www.google.com"
    Debug.Print IE.readyState
End Sub
```

I'm getting a very unusual bit of behaviour on this. The IE.navigate command works properly - the IE site loads up Google without any issue. But the IE.readyState information gives me error #462, "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". It's really strange to me that it knows how to deal with IE when navigating, but not when getting information. I've taken this code from online tutorials, and it works fine on my personal computer, but on my work computer I'm always getting this 462.

Also worth noting: I work at a bank, so it's possible that this could be some kind of workplace security thing. If anyone has seen that kind of behaviour before due to locked-down workplaces, please let me know.

Thanks.

Environment notes: Excel 2016 at work and Excel 2013 at home, IE version 20H2 at work and 22H2 at home, and Windows 10 in both cases. In the VBA I've added a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library, but nothing else beyond the defaults.

Comment: IE should no longer be used as MS is actively phasing it out. Google is probably not the site you want to work with either. If it is an intranet address in the bank, replace the line `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` with `Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")` This initialises IE via its GUID. More information here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/

Comment: This is just a one-off job, so I wanted to keep it simple for now. But I can play around with that GetObject code. I assume it's all the same code thereafter? 

And I was using Google as a test - the actual site I want is on the bank intranet, but that adds another layer of complexity to it, and I can't confirm that on my personal PC (or have you guys replicate it). So I figured I'd start on a simple public site, and once was working I could go from there.

Comment: Tried it, and with that GetObject code, it seems to be working now. Thank you!

Comment: It did not work before precisely because it is an intranet access. Using the GUID is the easiest way to work around the error. All the rest of the code remains the same, yes. Another method is to search all open windows via the shell to see if it is IE. The reference would then be passed to the origin variable. But this is unnecessarily complicated. Very good that it works now.

Comment: @Zwenn That is incredibly useful information! I wish I knew this about a year ago!